# How to use selected dropdown field in all the components

Tags: angular

I need to share the selected value in all the components,So that it can be used across all the components whenever it is necessary

Comment: use a global object (for example => selectedOption = {}) in component. When you change the select tag, you will be given the key for this variable.
`function change(key, value) {this.selectedOption[key] = value;}`

You now have access to selectedOption globsl variable in the entire template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use service for that

```
@Injectable({

   providedIn:"root" //Use this if you want to have shared on application level,otherwise provide in parent component level
    })
   export class SelectService{
       private _value:any;

   get value(){return this._value;
    }
    changeValue(value){
        this._value = value;
    }

  }
```

now you can inject service wherever you want and use it accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Here you are looking for a `Behavior Subject` in your service.

The concept here is that you create an object of type `BehaviorSubject` in your service to which others can subscribe and watch for changes.

Once the value changes, it is available to all the components subscribed to it.

It's value can be changed by calling the `next()` method on it.

A working sample can be found **[HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviour-subject-demo)**

Answer (score 0):

A convenient and scale able approach would be to use **Subjects** in you application.
An rxjs Subject is both an observer and an Observable, i.e you can use the same subject to multicast a value (that you want to share across the other components) and also use it to subscribe to any changes.

**Behavior Subject** is of the subjects in rxjs that may come in handy.
Use case:

- Create a subject in service :

  `export class dataService { mySubject: new BehaviorSubject<string>('initialValue');}`

In Component A subscribe to this subject (create an instance of dataService in your constructor):

```
this.service.mySubject.subscribe(data => { this.variableTOBeUpdated = data});
```

Similarly In Component B subscribe to this subject (create an instance of dataService in your constructor):
`this.service.mySubject.subscribe(data => { this.OthervariableTOBeUpdated = data});`

=> now suppose you want to update the value of the subject, simply set the new value as:
`this.service.mySubject.next('updatedValue');`

using the "next" you have set the updated value and the same will be updated wherever you have created the subcription, i.e. in both components the variable (`this.variableTOBeUpdated` and `this.OthervariableTOBeUpdated`) will be updated with latest value.